# Access higher level file in Bazel test

Tags: go, bazel

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
my/path/to/service
    └── internal
        └── module_name
            ├── BUILD.bazel
            ├── module_logic.go
            └── module_test.go 
    └── endpoint_1
        ├── BUILD.bazel
        ├── logic.go
        ├── logic_test.go
        └── variables_test.go
```

And a Go `BUILD.bazel` file set-up as follows:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library", "go_test")

go_library(
    name = "module_name",
    srcs = ["module_logic.go"],
    importpath = "github.com/path/service/internal/module_name",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//proto/path:go",
        "@org_golang_google_grpc//codes",
        "@org_golang_google_grpc//status",
    ],
)

go_test(
    name = "module_test",
    srcs = [
        "module_test.go",
        // endpoint_1/variables_test.go
    ],
    embed = [":pagination"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_stretchr_testify//assert",
        "@com_github_stretchr_testify//require",
    ],
)
```

Am I able to access the values of `variables_test.go` within `module_test.go`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically bazel targets only use files from their own package in `srcs`, and to get things in other packages, you use targets from that other package in `deps`.

So probably the right thing to do is make a `go_library` of what is shared between `module_test` and `variables_test` and have both depend on that in their deps, e.g. `//my/path/to/service/endpoint_1:variables`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access content another package as long as they are visible at the place of consumption. If your `endpoint_1/BUILD.bazel` said for instance:

```
exports_files(
    ["variables_test.go"],
    visibility = ["//internal/module_name:__pkg__"],
)
```

Then you could in `internal/module_name/BUILD.bazel` refer to `variables_test.go` using:

```
"//endpoint_1:variables_test.go"
```

But (and this is a very good point raised in another answer)... should you? If you need direct access to a (source) file in another package (and not a target made there; e.g. a library), it's probably a strong hint the packages layout (source tree) does not match well to the intended design / use. The likely answer really is: you should not.